# Docker container does not inherit ulimit from host

Tags: docker, ulimit

I have read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docker-user/limits/docker-user/T45Kc9vD804/v8J_N4gLbacJ) that `docker` containers inherit `ulimit` properties from the host. This does not seem to happen for my containers. In particular, I need the `max locked memory` property to inherit from host. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
ubuntu@host:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31404
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 50000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 50000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
ubuntu@host:~$ docker exec -it container /bin/bash
root@container:/# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31404
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 524288
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 524288
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What version of the docker server and client are you running? What is the host OS?

Comment: `Client:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 21:37:01 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 21:37:01 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
`

Comment: host OS is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-66-generic x86_64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set custom ulimits for a container, you can use the `--ulimit` option. For example;

```
docker run -it --rm --ulimit memlock=32768:32768 ubuntu sh -c "ulimit -a"
```

Shows:

```
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        8192
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 32
process              7873
nofiles              1024
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited
```

You can find more information in the documentation; https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

For other ways to restrict resources for a container, also see this section;
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources